# Global event not happening for all objects in emitter array?

Tags: node.js

Sorry if this is a beginner question, I am just starting to learn node.js

I wrote this code, and I was wondering why when it runs the output is

```
Hello, Bob
Bob was greeted
```

but I thought it should be

```
Hello, Bob
Bob was greeted
Bob was greeted
Bob was greeted
```

because all 3 greeter objects are added to the emitter array?

```
let EventEmitter = require('events');

class Greeter extends EventEmitter {

    constructor(name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.greeting = "Hello, " + this.name;
        this.on('greet', (greetor) => {
            console.log(greetor + ' was greeted');
        });
    }

    greet() {
        console.log(this.greeting);
        this.emit('greet', this.name);
    }
}

let greeter_0 = new Greeter('Bob');
let greeter_1 = new Greeter('Joe');
let greeter_2 = new Greeter('Jake');
greeter_0.greet();
```

Answer (score 1):

You've made three different, independent emitters and you are calling `greet()` on one of the them. Only objects listening for the `greet()` event on *that particular emitter* will be triggered. And you mention an array, but there's no arrays in your code.

If you wanted all to respond, you would have to send the greet event from each emitter:

```
greeter_0.greet();
greeter_1.greet();
greeter_2.greet();
```

It's not super clear what you are trying to do, but maybe this will help. If you have a bunch of person objects and single greeter emitter, you can have each person listen for the greet event like this:

```
let EventEmitter = require('events');

class Greeter extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    greet() {
        console.log("Start Greeting");
        this.emit('greet');
    }
}

class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name
    }
    listenForGreeting(emitter) {
        emitter.on('greet', () =>{
            console.log(this.name + ' was greeted')
        })
    }
}
let greetor = new Greeter()
let p0 = new Person('Bob');
p0.listenForGreeting(greetor)

let p1 = new Person('Joe');
p1.listenForGreeting(greetor)

let p3 = new Person('Jake');
p3.listenForGreeting(greetor)

greetor.greet()
```

Here each person is listening to the *same* emitter, so they all respond to the event.

Comment: Sorry about my naming, I can see how my intent isn't clear. I wanted each person to be able to be an event emitter, and when any one of those people would have their greet method called, the other 3 would get the message. In your code, greetor initiates the greeting, but I want one of the people to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by emitting and receiving from the prototype (and making the naming better).

```
let EventEmitter = require('events');

class Person extends EventEmitter {

    constructor(name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.loginMessage = `Hello, ${this.name}`;
        Person.prototype.on('login', (user) => {
            console.log(`${this.name}, ${user} logged in`);
        });
    }

    login() {
        console.log(this.loginMessage);
        Person.prototype.emit('login', this.name);
    }
}

let user_0 = new Person('Bob');
let user_1 = new Person('Joe');
let user_2 = new Person('Jake');
user_0.login();
```